# why ouput goes to infinite loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, int

if i used nounce = 32766 it only gives 1 time output but for 32767 it goes to infinite loop.....  why ??    same thing happen when i used int

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Mining
{
    short int Nounce;
};

int main() 
{
    Mining Mine;
    Mine.Nounce = 32767;

    for (short int i = 0; i <= Mine.Nounce; i++)
    {
        if (i == Mine.Nounce)
        {
            cout << " Nounce is " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if i used 32768 then no output but if i used  100000 then it says compiler error with overflow so why overflow happen at that no. 32767 ifact its last number .. overflow should be on 32768

Comment: Try running with the undefined behavior sanitizer.  If I remember correctly, the compiler is allowed to assume signed arithmetic will never overflow, so you're skirting with undefined behavior.

Comment: yes @FrançoisAndrieux When i used smaller value like 32766 it only gives 1 time output ..thats wht i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the largest possible positive value, every other value will be `<=` to it, so this loop goes on forever:

```
for(short int i=0;i<=Mine.Nounce;i++)
```

You can see that 32767 is the largest value for a `short` on your platform by using `numeric_limits`:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<short>::max() << std::endl; //32767
```

When `i` reaches 32767, `i++` will attempt to increment it. This is undefined behavior because of signed overflow, however most implementations (like your own apparently) will simply roll over to the maximum negative value, and then `i++` will happily increment up again.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric types have a limit to the range of values they can represent. It seems like the maximum value a `int short` can store on your platform is `32767`. So `i <= 32767` is necessarily true, there exists no `int short` that is larger than `32767` on your platform. This is also why the compiler complains when you attempt to assign `100000` to `Mine.Nounce`, it cannot represent that value. See [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to find out what the limits are for your platform.

To increment a signed integer variable that already has the largest possible representable value is undefined behavior. Your loop will eventually try to execute `i++` when `i == 32767` which will lead to undefined behavior.

Consider using a larger integer type. `int` is at least 32 bit on the majority of platforms, which would allow it to represent values up to `2147483647`. You could also consider using `unsigned short` which on your platform would likely be able to represent values up to `65535`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, `i` will never be greater than the value of `Mine.Nounce` because of the way that `short`s are represented in memory. Most implementations use 2 bytes for a `short` with one bit for the sign bit. Therefore , the maximum value that can be represented by a `signed short` is 2^15 - 1 = 32767.

Answer (score 0):

It goes to infinite loop because your program exhibits [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) due to a signed integer overflow.
Variable `i` of type `short` overflows **after** it reaches the value of `Mine.Nounce` which is `32767` which is probably the [max value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) `short` can hold on your implementation. You should change your condition to:

```
i < Mine.Nounce
```

which will keep the value of `i` at bay.